# Explanation about Supervisor and tail over Apache's error.log

Tags: docker, supervisord, tail, docker-entrypoint

While creating a Docker Container, to have both **apache2** `error.log` and tail it via `docker logs -f <my_container>` I use a container that runs **supervisor** as **entrypoint** with this configurations:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon = true
environment = PLACEHOLDER=true
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0

[program:apache]
command=apache2ctl -DFOREGROUND
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=1
startsecs=1
stderr_logfile=/var/log/apache2/error.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/apache2/access.log
user=root
killasgroup=true
stopasgroup=true

[program:apache2-error]
command= tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
autostart = true
autorestart = true
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0

[program:apache2-access]
command= tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log
autostart = true
autorestart = true
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

this works fine, but I don't understand why this not works if I replace the `[program:apache]` session with this:

```
[program:apache]
command=apache2ctl -DFOREGROUND
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=1
startsecs=1
user=root
killasgroup=true
stopasgroup=true
```

That is: without explicitly setting the `stderr` and `stdout` logfile the `docker logs -f <my_container>` command not works, but inside container `tail -f /var/logs/apache2/access.log` and `tail -f /var/logs/apache2/error.log` work fine.

Someone can explain me why `supervisor` and `docker logs -f <my_container>` has two different works due to this configurations changes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Supervisor can 'see' the stdout of apache2 and write it down to a file that you specify with *stdout_file*. The thing is that apache2 does not write it access log to stdout, it writes it to the file in /var/log/apache2.

So, what you are seeing in `docker logs -f` is the tailing that supervisor is doing to the file that you provided in `stdout_file` and supervisor is forwarding it to its own `stdout` as you configured in `[supervosord]`.

Therefore, when you remove the apache2 log file config from supervisor, there is no such forwarding; and apache2 continues writing to the same file as before.

So, what you need to do is tell Apache to write its access log to /dev/stdout instead of a file in disk. You can do that in the Apache virtualhost configuration.

The same thing for `stderr`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't understand a thing: theoretically the section `[program:apache2-access]` section is tailing the `access.log` file, so I thought that the output coming from this section should be captured by `docker logs -f`. Why isn't so?